# undefined reference to symbol dgemm cblas error

Tags: compiling, ld

I am trying to compile a code package, which makes use of cblas and Lapack. Thus, after specifying the path of Lapack and cblas in its makefile, when I try to make or compile, I get the following error

```
   undefined reference to symbol 'dgemm_'
    'dgemm_' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf so try adding it to the linker        
    command line
```

If anybody has faced this error earlier, can you please tell me how to resolve it? I tried to search and ended up here,

```
    http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=620434
```

I dunno if this is the right direction, but please help me out here. Am just stuck, trying to compile few codes. The major thing I want to know is how to do this -

```
    'dgemm_' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf so try adding it to the linker        
    command line
```

Its just my thought, but will this solve the problem? Please help me.

Comment: Did you try linking with BLAS by using -lblas? The static BLAS library should be part of the package [libblas-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libblas-dev)

Comment: hi, i had same error.

Comment: hey @stackprogramer. I guess I solved it, but do not remember now how I did that. Can back track if you want.

Comment: can you share your solution thanks  if you remembered

Comment: which package are you trying to compile? I was doing this for bundler .

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan I am also trying to compile bundler and running into this issue. Any chance you remember how you fixed it?

Comment: @faeophyta will check on this and get back to you mate.